# How to auto refresh summary screen

Tags: drupal

When a relationship is added to a contact using the contact summary screen, the tab that indicates the number of relationships doesn't change to indicate the extra relationship. For example, if there were no relationships previously, the tab stays at 'Relationships - 0' until the screen is refreshed.  Is there a setting or some way of forcing the summary screen to refresh when such a change is made?

Comment: I expect this is more information and not a clear enough answer, but this case has some useful information related to this problem: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16016/how-do-i-force-a-reload-after-a-civicrm-summary-action

Comment: Thanks, saw that but I was hoping to avoid any coding